# WNA3100 Wifi usb adapter won't connect

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, usb

I followed the guide here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221251

to install the drivers for my Netgear wifi usb adapter WNA3100.

I managed to install the drivers correctly but before and after a reboot, When I connect to my wireless network, it keeps asking for my password and never actually connects.

lsusb http://pastebin.com/SzeVNA2t

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do an ifconfig to see what interface designation the adapter has been given(wlan0, wlan1 etc.) then make sure in your wireless settings for your access point that that particular interface is selected.